# Java: File not opening giving exceptions

Tags: java, file, exception, jpcap

I am taking a file name via filenamechooser and sending it it my desired method for processing but the problem is that it is not accepting the filename.I am using JPcap for opening up the file.When i hard code it ,It gives me perfect results but when i send the file name it gives me exception.Here is my code

```
         JpcapCaptor captor = JpcapCaptor.openFile("E:\\10.pcap");
```

I took the printing statement of this file and it gives me this

```
          System.out.println("E:\\10.pcap");
```

on Console i get this

E:\10.pcap

but when i send this filename from my GUI to this openfile function it gives me this exception although when i take the printing statement of this filename it is also the same E:\10.pcap

```
      SEVERE: null
     java.io.IOException: E:\10.pcap
    : Invalid argument
    at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.openFile(JpcapCaptor.java:93)
    at dpi.Functions.PortBasedAnalysis(Functions.java:52)
    at dpi.GraphicalInterface.jButton1MouseClicked(GraphicalInterface.java:104)
    at dpi.GraphicalInterface.access$000(GraphicalInterface.java:25)
    at dpi.GraphicalInterface$1.mouseClicked(GraphicalInterface.java:49)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6041)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3995)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at      java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

are you sure this file actually exists? maybe you need to create it first?

try

```
File f = new File("E:\\10.pcap");
if(!f.exists()){
  f.createFile(); //or create()  - i forget
}
//then do the pcap shit
```

Comment: or you could use try{}catch(Exception ex){}